# Property is null after adding subview

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, addsubview

I'm launching a UIPopoverViewController that is supposed to draw two buttons (add and delete buttons). The ContentViewController for the UIPopover has a property called `outputJackView` that is set just before the UIPopoverViewController is launched. This property is necessary for the buttons to draw properly. The problem is right after the first button is added as a subview, the `outputJackView` is set to null somehow.

Here is the ContentViewController for UIPopoverViewController:

CableConnectionMenuController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class JackView;

@interface CableConnectionMenuController : UIViewController
{
JackView *outputJackView;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CableConnectionDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) JackView *outputJackView;

- (void)setButtonTextWithOutputJack:(JackView *)outputJack withInputArray:(NSMutableArray *)inputArray;
- (void)createAddConnectionButton;
- (void)createDeleteConnectionButton;
@end
```

CableConnectionMenuController.m

```
#import "CableConnectionMenuController.h"
#import "JackView.h"
#import "CableDisconnectButton.h"

@implementation CableConnectionMenuController

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize outputJackView;
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//alloc output jack view
self.outputJackView = [[JackView alloc] init];

//set size of popover view in cables view
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

//change view background color
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

//this method is called from the class that launches the UIPopoverViewController
- (void)setButtonTextWithOutputJack:(JackView *)outputJack withInputArray:(NSMutableArray *)inputArray
{
//set output jack which will be the same for all inputs
self.outputJackView = outputJack;

//draw add connection button
[self createAddConnectionButton];

//draw delete connection button - not working
//[self createDeleteConnectionButton];
}

- (void)createAddConnectionButton
{
CableDisconnectButton *addConnectionButton = [CableDisconnectButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
addConnectionButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 190, 40);
[addConnectionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images/cable_connect_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addConnectionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images/cable_connect_button_over.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

//add output jack
addConnectionButton.outputJack = self.outputJackView;

//add action to button
[addConnectionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addConnectionButtonTarget:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSLog(@"output jack name before: %@", self.outputJackView.jackName);

[self.view addSubview:addConnectionButton];

NSLog(@"output jack name after: %@", self.outputJackView.jackName);
}
```

The two NSLog's at the end return the name correctly on the first one (before) and return null on the second (after). The `jackName` properties are NSString's. It's obvious that the property is being set to null after a subview is added, but I can't figure out why that would happen.

Here is the method from the class that launches the UIPopoverViewController in case it matters:

```
- (void)editCableConnectionsWith:(JackView *)outputJack
{
//launches the note menu popover
self.cableConnectionMenuController = [[CableConnectionMenuController alloc] init];
self.cableConnectionMenuController.delegate = (id)self;

//find appropriate connection to edit
for (JackView *currentJack in jackArray)
{
    if (currentJack == outputJack)
    {
        //create temp array of input jacks to send to cable connection controller
        NSMutableArray *inputButtonTempArray = [self returnInputJackArrayWithOutputJack:currentJack];

        //set information for creating disconnect buttons in popover
        [self.cableConnectionMenuController setButtonTextWithOutputJack:currentJack withInputArray:inputButtonTempArray];
    }
}

self.editConnectionsPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.cableConnectionMenuController];

[self.editConnectionsPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:pulseRing.frame inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: After further testing, it appears ALL properties in this UIViewController are set to null after a subview is added. This really makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

How is the jackName property declared?  My guess is that it's a weak reference.

I had a similar issue where a weak reference on a view was reset after the view was added as a subview.  My understanding is that a weak reference should only be used when there's a potential retain cycle (e.g. you have a backpack with a reference to a calculator and the calculator points back to the backpack--see the [Big Nerd Ranch book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321821521)).

I'm not quite sure why that's an issue here, but I encountered something similar and figured I'd share.